# "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

### Unable to solve the problem by enabling the google access to less secure apps and two-step verification

*I have enabled the google access to less secure apps but I'm still encountering the issue..
I have even tried to enable two-step verification, but it couldn't work as well..*

```
Protected Sub sendMail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sendMail.Click
        Dim mainconn As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("user_ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(mainconn)

        Dim query As String = "Select email, password from user_information where email = @email"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, con)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtBoxEmailSupport.Text.Trim)
        con.Open()
        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        If sdr.Read() Then

            Dim email_password As String = sdr("email").ToString.Trim
            Dim password_reset As String = sdr("password").ToString.Trim

            Dim mm As New MailMessage("jackieyong36@gmail.com", txtBoxEmailSupport.Text.Trim)
            mm.Subject = "Your forgotten Password!"
            mm.Body = String.Format("Smtp is working, man~~", email_password, password_reset)
            mm.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            smtp.EnableSsl = True
            Dim nc As New NetworkCredential("jackieyong36gmail.com", "12345")
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            smtp.Credentials = nc
            smtp.Port = 587
            smtp.Send(mm)

            lblStatus.Text = "Your password has been sent to " + txtBoxEmailSupport.Text

        Else
            lblStatus.Text = "This email was not existed!"

        End If
```

Comment: Yikes, this is some scary password handling. It's **NEVER** okay to send a lost password to the user. Instead, you store additional information they can use to _reset_ the password. **You shouldn't even have the password saved anywhere that it would be possible to send it to the user.** Again: _don't store the password at all!_ You store a **hash** of the password (which is not the same as encryption). Hash values cannot be reversed. When the user tries to log in, you also hash the attempted password, and then compare the hash values. Anything else is **not okay**, even for testing/learning.

Comment: Can give some examples?

Comment: @JackieYong [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) provides a lot of valuable information.

Comment: @AndrewMorton OK, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I already solved this problem with auth, this code works for me, download [MailKit from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) and add to your references.. you need to enable only less secure apps.

```
Private Sub SendMail()
    Dim message = New MimeMessage()
    message.From.Add(New MailboxAddress("Mr. Kako Kak", "yourgmail@gmail.com"))
    message.[To].Add(New MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "hisgmail@gmail.com"))
    message.Subject = "subjectText"
    message.Body = New TextPart("plain") With {
        .Text = "bodyText"
    }

    Using client = New SmtpClient()
        client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2")
        client.Authenticate("yourgmail@gmail.com", "yourgmailpswd")
        client.Send(message)
        client.Disconnect(True)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: But it shows me AuthenticationMechanisms, Connect.. all these are not the members of SmtpClient..

Comment: yes, sorry, SmtpClient is not from .NET framework, but from MailKit, change your reference and methods will shown up

Comment: The error still remain the same. Can refer to the topic of this question

Comment: @Jackie Yong - but code is not the same, so in which line is an error and what?

Comment: Actually it shows no error with the codes, it just reveal that "SMTP server requires a secure connection.... "